# How do you write a json4s CustomSerializer that handles collections

Tags: scala, functional-programming, deserialization, json4s

I have a class that I am trying to deserialize using the json4s `CustomSerializer` functionality.  I need to do this due to the [inability of json4s to deserialize mutable collections](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/138).

This is the basic structure of the class I want to deserialize (don't worry about why the class is structured like this):

```
case class FeatureValue(timestamp:Double)

object FeatureValue{
  implicit def ordering[F <: FeatureValue] = new Ordering[F] {
    override def compare(a: F, b: F): Int = {
      a.timestamp.compareTo(b.timestamp)
    }
  }
}

class Point {
  val features = new HashMap[String, SortedSet[FeatureValue]]

  def add(name:String, value:FeatureValue):Unit = {
    val oldValue:SortedSet[FeatureValue] = features.getOrElseUpdate(name, SortedSet[FeatureValue]())
    oldValue += value
  }
}
```

Json4s serializes this just fine.  A serialized instance might look like the following:

```
{"features":
  {
   "CODE0":[{"timestamp":4.8828914447482E8}],
   "CODE1":[{"timestamp":4.8828914541333E8}],
   "CODE2":[{"timestamp":4.8828915127325E8},{"timestamp":4.8828910097466E8}]
  }
}
```

I've tried writing a custom deserializer, but I don't know how to deal with the list tails.  In a normal matcher you can just call your own function recursively, but in this case the function is anonymous and being called through the json4s API.  I cannot find any examples that deal with this and I can't figure it out.

Currently I can match only a single hash key, and a single `FeatureValue` instance in its value.  Here is the CustomSerializer as it stands:

```
import org.json4s.{FieldSerializer, DefaultFormats, Extraction, CustomSerializer}
import org.json4s.JsonAST._

class PointSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Point](format => (
  {
    case JObject(JField("features", JObject(Nil)) :: Nil) => new Point
    case JObject(List(("features", JObject(List(
      (feature:String, JArray(List(JObject(List(("timestamp",JDouble(ts)))))))))
    ))) => {
      val point = new Point
      point.add(feature, FeatureValue(ts))
      point
    }
  },
  {
    // don't need to customize this, it works fine
    case x: Point => Extraction.decompose(x)(DefaultFormats + FieldSerializer[Point]())
  }
  ))
```

If I try to change to using the :: separated list format, so far I have gotten compiler errors.  Even if I didn't get compiler errors, I am not sure what I would do with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the list of json features in your pattern match and then map over this list to get the `Feature`s and their codes.

```
class PointSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Point](format => (
  {
    case JObject(List(("features", JObject(featuresJson)))) => 
      val features = featuresJson.flatMap { 
        case (code:String, JArray(timestamps)) =>
          timestamps.map { case JObject(List(("timestamp",JDouble(ts)))) =>
            code -> FeatureValue(ts)
          }
      }

      val point = new Point
      features.foreach((point.add _).tupled)
      point
  }, {
    case x: Point => Extraction.decompose(x)(DefaultFormats + FieldSerializer[Point]())
  }
))
```

Which deserializes your json as follows :

```
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new PointSerializer

val json = """
{"features":
  {
   "CODE0":[{"timestamp":4.8828914447482E8}],
   "CODE1":[{"timestamp":4.8828914541333E8}],
   "CODE2":[{"timestamp":4.8828915127325E8},{"timestamp":4.8828910097466E8}]
  }
}
"""

val point0 = read[Point]("""{"features": {}}""")
val point1 = read[Point](json)

point0.features // Map()
point1.features 
// Map(
//   CODE0 -> TreeSet(FeatureValue(4.8828914447482E8)), 
//   CODE2 -> TreeSet(FeatureValue(4.8828910097466E8), FeatureValue(4.8828915127325E8)), 
//   CODE1 -> TreeSet(FeatureValue(4.8828914541333E8))
// )
```